# Python - Subprocess and graph output

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently launching a python script from within another python script (the reason I am doing this is mainly to keep things organised and clear for the reader, it has a "main" script that launches all the other ones). I am using the following command :

```
try:
p = subprocess.run("python myScriptOne.py", 
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
                   check=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
print(e.stderr)
```

The script normally outputs graphs on a detached window if ran directly. When using subprocess, I can't see the graph outputting. Is there a way to still see the graphs popping on separate windows while using subprocess ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just `import` the other script and run its functionality directly instead of going via `subprocess`?

Comment: In my opinion, no because this loses readability since then I would have to put data and functions in the 'main' sctipt

Comment: I don't understand that reasoning. If your `"myScriptOne.py"` exposes a single main function to call into (from your 'main' script) the code would actually be shorter than what you have now (without needing to add any "data and functions" in the 'main' script)

Comment: You are probably right regarding the organisation of the files.